# Method which returns the color of a label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to program 'The Game of Life' using Tkinter. Since I want to check the status of the neighbouring nodes using colours, I would like to know if there is a method which returns the colour of a label.

Thanks!

```
def checkNeighbours(i,j):
    alive_nodes=0
    if(labels[i+1][j].getColor()=="black"): 
        alive_nodes+=1
    if(labels[i][j+1].getColor()=="black"): 
        alive_nodes+=1
    if(labels[i-1][j].getColor()=="black"): 
        alive_nodes+=1
    if(labels[i][j-1].getColor()=="black"): 
        alive_nodes+=1
    if(labels[i+1][j+1].getColor()=="black"):   
        alive_nodes+=1
    if(labels[i-1][j-1].getColor()=="black"):   
        alive_nodes+=1
    if(labels[i+1][j-1].getColor()=="black"):   
        alive_nodes+=1
    if(labels[i-1][j+1].getColor()=="black"):   
        alive_nodes+=1
    return alive_nodes
```

Comment: Please provide relevant parts of the code you have written so far, and an example of what you would expect the code to do.

Comment: `color = label_name["background"]` You can use this method to return other things as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`cget`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method) to get the value of a widget's configuration options. Example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
root = Tk()
label = Label(text="hello", bg="red")
print("This label's color is:", label.cget("bg"))
```

Result:

```
This label's color is: red
```

You can also index the widget with the option name, e.g. `label["bg"]`.